# I'm getting an error in the following program as KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

Here is my code-

```
import pandas as pd

df5=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Anaconda3\airtravel.csv')

print(df5)

   Month   "1958"   "1959"   "1960"
0    JAN      340      360      417
1    FEB      318      342      391
2    MAR      362      406      419
3    APR      348      396      461
4    MAY      363      420      472
5    JUN      435      472      535
6    JUL      491      548      622
7    AUG      505      559      606
8    SEP      404      463      508
9    OCT      359      407      461
10   NOV      310      362      390
11   DEC      337      405      432
```

But when I try to access this:-

```
print(df5['1960'])
```

I get an error.

```
KeyError: '1960'
```

I can't understand why is that happening.
File link: [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/csv.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/csv.html)

Thanks

Comment: do `df5.columns` to see what the column name is, but, based on your sample data, it looks like it should be `df5[' "1960"']`

Answer (score 1):

Your column includes quotations along with the column name. maybe `df5['"1960"']` would work

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this file. We have two problems here. In the column names there is a space at the beginning and "" between the years.

Possible solutions:

- Put a parameter 'skipinitialspace'. It will remove spaces and quatation marks. Then you can print it like you wanted:

  ```
   df5 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Anaconda3\airtravel.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
   print(df5['1960'])
  ```
- Remove spaces on both sides and add "" to the name:

  ```
  df5 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Anaconda3\airtravel.csv')
  df5.columns = [x.strip() for x in df5.columns]
  print(df5['"1960"'])
  ```
- Leave it at it is and add space at the beginning:

  ```
  df5 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Anaconda3\airtravel.csv')
  print(df5[' "1960"'])
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. I also removed the spaces from the original file and was able to print it as df5['1960']. So I guess print(df5['1960']) will only work if there would be no spaces.